# How to validate if my user has an ADM account based on samaccountname

Tags: powershell

I would like to validate if my standard user has an admin account in AD.

Example, the samaccountname of Smith, Joe is SmithJ. I want to check if he has an ADMSmithJ in the AD

```
$samaccountname = Read-Host "Please type the samaccountname"
$AdUser = get-aduser $samaccountname -Properties samaccountname

Try { get-aduser "adm"$samaccountname? -Properties samaccountname

}catch{ write-host "the user $samaccountname doesnt have a priviledge (Adm) Account."

}
```

Comment: The naming convention is always Surname + 1st character of GivenName?

Comment: Exactly. If my Lastname is Moody and my first name is Tom, it will be MoodyT the regular account and if he has a priviledge account it will be admMoodyT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this, instead of `try` / `catch`, I would personally filter for a user having `Name` or `SamAccountName`:

```
$account = Read-Host "Please type the SamAccountName"
try {
    $adUser  = Get-ADUser $account
    $admUser = 'adm' + $adUser.Surname + $adUser.GivenName[0]
    if($adUser = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(|(name=$admUser)(samAccountName=$admUser))") {
        # if the AD object exists in AD, return the object
        $adUser
    }
    else {
        "No user found with SamAccountName '$admUser' in AD."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $_
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks Santiago. What is [0] for?

Comment: If i have 5 users to validate, is it possible to do it with a Read-host separate by ";" ?

Comment: @ak2595 yeah you could `.Split(';')` and then loop each user using the same logic. That wasn't part of the question tho

Comment: @ak2595 `$adUser.GivenName[0]` is the 1st character of the user's GivenName attribute

Comment: Just curious. Why not just do this in one line? ```Get-ADUser -Identity "adm$(Read-Host 'Please type the SamAccountName'))"```

Comment: @postanote is the question directed to me or to OP?

Comment: '@Santiago Squarzon'...  Either actually.

Comment: @postanote because the admin account is not the user's `samaccountname` with prepended `adm`, it's actually `adm` + the user's `surname` + the first character of the user's `givenname`